# How do I print complete element arrays in Jint - like you can with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, jint

I'm trying to access a `Javascript` `array` through `Jint`. We're basically accepting custom `javascript` code in an application that works across a variety of platforms and are using `Jint` for `.NET`. We need the result to be the same - whether it's in `.NET` or vanilla `JavaScript`.

```
        private Engine _engine = new Engine();
        var testList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        _engine.SetValue("testList", testList);
        var result = _engine.Execute("'Elements of the array are: ' + testList").GetCompletionValue();
        var finalVal = result.AsString();
```

I would expect the result to be:

`Elements of the array are: 1,2,3,4,5` (similar to vanilla `JavaScript`)

However, it throws an exception.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No matching indexer found.
```

Note that if I try to access just one element of the array (eg `testList[1]`) it works fine.

Am I doing something wrong here? If not, then can I implement a custom indexer to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

surround your testList with `Array.from()`. see example below

```
    private Engine _engine = new Engine();
    var testList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    _engine.SetValue("testList", testList);
    var result = _engine.Execute("'Elements of the array are: ' + Array.from(testList)").GetCompletionValue();
    var finalVal = result.AsString();
```